# How to retrieve JSON-data from PHP-file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a form that submits data to a file called 'submit_link.php'. To submit the entered form values I am using this function with jQuery:

```
function submitLink() {
    if ($('#lnk_email2').val().length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<?php echo $setting['site_url'] .'/';?>includes/misc/submit_link.php',
            data:$('#add_link_form').serialize(),

            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#lnk_exch_ini').remove();
                $('#loader_submit').css('display', 'block').html("<img src='<?php echo $setting['site_url'] . $setting['template_url'] .'/';?>images/loader.gif' />");
            },

            error: function() {

            },

            success: function() {
                $('#loader_submit').remove();
            },

            complete: function() {
                $('#lnk_exch_content').load('includes/forms/add_link_form2.php');
            }
        });
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is the file submit_link.php:

```
if ($user['login_status'] == 1) {
    $email = $user['email'];
    $submitter = $user['id'];
}
else {
    $submitter = 0;
}

if (strpos($url, "http://") === false) {
    $url = 'http://'.$url;
}

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO ava_links SET name='$anchor', url = '$url', description = '$description', sitewide = 1, published = 0, 
submitter = $submitter, submitter_email = '$email'") or die (mysqli_error($con));

$link_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$referral_link = $setting['site_url'].'/?r='.$link_id;

$step2 = LINK_EXCHANGE_STEP2;
```

Now my problem is that I want the last three variables $link_id, $referral_link and $step2 returned from the server via json. How do I do this? How can I use the json-encoded data inside of my function submitLink() I posted above? How can I access each of the objects stored inside the json-data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a php array:

```
$output=array('link_id'=>$link_id, 'referral_link'=>$referral_link);
```

Then :

```
  echo json_encode( $output):
```

Set `dataType:'json'` in the `$.ajax` options also, then consume the json in your success callback

Comment: Just one question: why do I have to echo json in my PHP-file?

Comment: aren't you wanting the json returned to client ( browser) as part of ajax request? If so have to tell php to send it thus `echo`

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll check it out - one minute. I'm sorry for that question but I do not have very much json-experience yet.

Comment: as can see is quite simple at server... create the json string from php array or object, then send it out. There are lots of tutorials on web and lots of posst on this site how to parse json to html in javascript/jQuery if that's your next step

Comment: I get this error: 'parsererror SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<''

How to deal with this kind of error?

Comment: inspect the request in browser console...can see exactly what is being sent. Make sure the only echo that occurs in whole server file is the json. Might have server side error spitting out message in html. Hard to say without knowing more about what exactly is being sent. And you can inspect that

Comment: This may be a stupid question but how do you debug a JSON-callback? Currently I'm using Safari 5 but I do have Chrome installed, also. Inside of the web inspector I can see the AJAX-requests and that's all...

Comment: in chrome hit F12....look in network tab and start clciking as deep as you can to find request status, response , headers etc on the request to your url. Can also remove the dataType and `console.log(serverresponseargument)` within success callback and see it there too. Lots of tutorials on basic ajax debugging on web

Comment: console.log(data) shows html content. I have the feeling that data contains html-content but don't know why it's there and how to replace it with json.

Comment: something not right in output file. I suspected was html from the `<`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use following PHP script.

```
<?php

//set header for JSON response
header("Content-Type: application/json");

//render array in JSON format
echo json_encode(array('status' => 200, 'data' => array('link_id'=>$link_id, 'referral_link'=>$referral_link)));
```

always have status code in response to check whether this response contains success or error,
according to this status code use jQuery to interact with User.

here is complete tutorial to fetch JSON response using jQuery
http://zainultutorials.blogspot.in/2013/10/ajax-how-to-retrieve-json-response-from.html